# Two meanings of [task-management]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

People use [task-managment](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/task-managment) in two very different ways: first very similar to [project-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management), second for questions related to OS-level task management.

I think the first case should be forbidden (with a comment in tag description), only [project-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) used for such questions.

BTW there is a typo in tag name

Answer (score 3):

Good point! I just created that tag-wiki accordingly (and re-tagged the two non-matching questions). One more thought here is that in the future we might need a third variant of "task manager": todo lists. As for now, they should fit into [project-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) (project: "My Tasks" :D).

Comment: There is [time-management] for todo-lists

Comment: Yuck! Must have missed that. *writing tag-wiki...*

Answer (score 2):

I second Izzy's recommendation for [project-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) for one of the meanings.

On top of that, use [process-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process-management) for tasks-in-OS-sense. This has a benefit of both not using the (now-can-be-banned) confusing dual meaning tag; AND being more technically accurate, since they are called Processes on virtually every OS, even Windows ("Process Explorer" is what people with a clue use instead of "Task Manager")